# dataframe to ArcGIS ASCII in R

Tags: r, ascii, arcgis

I have a data frame (predHB.Lv1Hard) that contains 3 columns "y" = Longitude, "x" = Latitude and "predLv1Hard" = probability of a model output.  All columns are numeric.

```
> head(predHB.Lv1Hard)
      y        x      predLv1Hard
1 -21.78557 114.0319  0.00000000
2 -21.78557 114.0319  0.06315789
3 -21.78557 114.0320  0.00000000
4 -21.78557 114.0320  0.00000000
5 -21.78557 114.0321  0.00000000
6 -21.78557 114.0321  0.00000000
```

I am trying to work out how to now export this to an ASCII that I can open in ArcGIS (either in .txt or ideally, .asc format).

The code (SPlus) that I'm trying to emulate is shown below (there doesn't seem to be an equivalent export.data function in R.)

```
export.data(DataSet = "predHB.Lv1Hard", Columns ="ALL", Rows = "ALL", Delimiter = ",", ColumnNames = T, 
FileName="C:/working/predHBLv1Hard.txt" , FileType="ASCII")
```

Comment: Sure there is. `write.table`with all of its delicious arguments.

Comment: I had tried using write.table but it seemed to mess around with column names and also not export properly, are you able to elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be a bit more specific as to what is messed up... feel free to edit what you've tried into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the package `raster`.

You first need convert the dataframe to a raster file (re-arrange the columns to match xyz):

```
r <- rasterFromXYZ(predHB.Lv1Hard[,c(2,1,3)])
```

and then use:

```
writeRaster(r,'filename.asc', format='ascii')
```

If the points are not in a regular grid, you can try the function `rasterize`. There is not much I can do with the head of that file but an example could be:

```
# Convert to SpatialPoinDataFrane
coordinates(predHB.Lv1Hard) <- ~x+y

# Calculate the extent of the observations
ext <- extent(predHB.Lv1Hard)

# Get the distance between points
table(diff(predHB.Lv1Hard@coords[,1]))
#0 0.00010000000000332 
#3                   2
# With the limited info I have I could assume that the resolution is 0.00010000000000332 degrees.
# If you know the original resolution, much better.

# Create the template
r <- raster(ext=ext,res=0.00010000000000332)
# Final raster
to_ascii <- rasterize(predHB.Lv1Hard, r, 'predLv1Hard')

# Write raster to ascii
writeRaster(to_ascii,'filename.asc', format='ascii')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I get the error "Error in rasterFromXYZ(predHB.Lv1Hard[, c(2, 1, 3)]) : 
  x cell sizes are not regular"

Comment: does the data need to be an even square/rectangle for this to work?

Comment: According to the error message, yes.
A second alternative is to use `rasterize`, but to do that you need to create a raster template.

Comment: oh wow, amazing! that seems to have done the trick!
In terms of resolution the data is at 5 x 5 m (but I will also be working at 2 x 2 m) is that what you were working with there? This is at -21 to -22 degrees lat

Comment: Well, what I calculated is around 10m resolution, but I just used the first 6 points. If you do it with all the points it should give you a more precise estimation.

Comment: ah yes I get it now, using table to identify the most common distance, thank you so much!